# Intercept Http call in Android and serve content locally

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

I have an iframe in an html page which has an iframe which loads some HTMl from server. I am able to intercept the http call and able to server the local HTML file(i.e exampleString in below method). Though the HTMl is getting rendered properly in the iframe but the inline javascript on click of button is not executing. Is there something I am doing wrong?
I already have below set and also setJavaScripEnabled as true.
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient())

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

```
       @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)

        {
            if (dismissDialogFlag == true) {
                dismissDialogFlag = false;
                result.confirm();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
```

}

public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {

```
 if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("https://test.contoso.com:444//WebResources/new_test123")) {
                WebResourceResponse wr1 = createHTMLResponse();
                return wr1;
            }
```

}

public WebResourceResponse createHTMLResponse() {

```
        String exampleString = "<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\" >function clickMe(){alert('!NO!');} </script></head><body>k123456 <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"clickMe()\">Click Me!</button></body></html>";

            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleString.getBytes());
        return  new WebResourceResponse("text/html", "UTF-8", stream);
}
```

Comment: how do you intercept the HTTP call?